# imwrite write on usb drive

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to write, in Python, an image on a USB drive using "imwrite" function. This is my code:

```
       _, img = camera.read()
       print("saved!")
       global img_counter
       img_name = "snapshot/opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
       cv2.imwrite(img_name,img)
```

In this way I write an image in a folder. If I put:

```
  img_name = "/mnt/usbdrive/imgtest/opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
```

like path (obviously after the mounting), the image is not saved on usb drive.

Any idea?

Comment: you get an error or it just isn't there?

Comment: Unfortunately no error, just not saved the image...